# Arduino Serial Communication: Local Echo Human character input

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

I'm using an Arduino Duemilanove to run some tests.  I'm communicating with the arduino over a serial port.  All i'm trying to do is read in a couple of ints, and i'm using the parseInt() function for its simplicity.

My question is, is there a way to program the ardunino to echo back each character as it is entered while still making use of the parseInt() function?

I know there are typically options to turn on local echo in a terminal clients, but i'd rather not rely on these.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    unsigned int timeTotal;
    Serial.print("Enter Total Time of Period (ms): "); 
    while (!Serial.available()) {   ;   }    //wait for input
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        //Serial.write(Serial.peek());
        timeTotal = Serial.parseInt();      //read int
        Serial.read();              //discard newline char at end of input
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Total Time: ");
        Serial.println(timeTotal, DEC);
    }
```

as you can see, i was trying to use a peek() but that only gets me one character....

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Do you want the program on the computer to return each character as it comes in?

Comment: no, I would like to read the data from the serial port as an integer (ie. 1000 or 500) but I was wondering if there is an arduino Serial or Stream library function that will print each character to the serial port but maybe not remove it from stdin so a function like parseInt() can interpret it.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You can just read the 4 bytes making an int from the serial port by calling Serial.peek() 4 times.

Comment: Does calling Serial.peek() repeatedly get all 4 characters, or just the same waiting character 4 times?  I am inclined to think the later.  Perhapse MRT89 could test this out and let us know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read characters into a string (echoing them as you go) until your hit you delimiter.  Then convert the string with `atoi()`.  Without looking at the source, I am sure this ia what parseInt does anyway.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Atoi was giving weird results at first, but i realized i wasn't null-terminating my string.  Thanks though!